# What is the fastest way for search a string with specific format in a file?

Tags: c#, string, full-text-search

I want to find the string below in a file. What is the best way to implement it?

```
drop%table_name
```

star(`%`) means you can have unlimited word in between on drop and table_name

I don't want to read file word by word and process it.

Currently I am using the richtextbox feature for find one word it is working fine but I don't know how to handle two word with some other word in middle. Please help me.

I put part of my code which is working fine for look for one string.

```
rtb1.Text = utility.readFile(file.Path);

int index = 0;
string searchTxt = "table_name";
while (index < rtb1.Text.LastIndexOf(searchTxt))
{
    rtb1.Find(searchTxt, index, rtb1.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
    rtb1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
    index = rtb1.Text.IndexOf(searchTxt, index) + 1;
}
```

sample of input:

```
drop TABLE mys u_web
/
aLter table  web_cusss rename some other name;
alter table abc

/

drop TABLE mysq weation;
drop TABLE my web_quiciary     /
drop  TABLE web_qudetails;
alter table web_qegy_details modify v_table varchar2(200);
alter table                  web_ition add d_date date;
```

My new Code:

```
 foreach (AMH_FileDetails file in fileList)
            {
                fileIssue += file.ToString();

                if (file.Type.Equals("SQL") || file.Type.Equals("TXT"))
                {
                    string fileBody = utility.readFile(file.Path).ToUpper();
                    foreach (string searchTxt in splittedTblName)
                    {

                        string pattern = @"DROP (.*?) " + searchTxt;
                        string input = fileBody;
                        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                        {
                            fileIssue += match.Value + " (drop table " + searchTxt + ") at poition" + match.Index + Environment.NewLine;
                            Console.WriteLine("{0} (drop table '{1}') at position {2}",
                                              match.Value, searchTxt, match.Index);
                        }

                        pattern = @"ALTER\s*TABLE\s*" + searchTxt + "(.*?)[;/]";
                        input = fileBody;
                        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline))
                        {
                            fileIssue += match.Value + " (Alter table " + searchTxt + ") at poition" + match.Index + Environment.NewLine;
                            Console.WriteLine("{0} (alter table '{1}') at position {2}",
                                              match.Value, searchTxt, match.Index);
                        }

                    }
                    //MessageBox.Show(fileIssue);

                }
                rtb1.Text = fileIssue;
                rtb1.SelectAll();
                rtb1.Copy();
                rtb1.DeselectAll();
            }
```

Comment: I would suggest using Regex.

Comment: @JoachimGotzes: any good example?

Comment: [Tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bvsy7wshy9sir5x/Regex-Tutorial.pdf?dl=0) this is a good tutorial for starting with regex.

Comment: @JoachimGotzes: is it Swedish? any idea can I combine regex with richTextBox for searching?

Comment: It is in english, you can use Regex on any string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You task can easily be accomplished by using regular expressions like this:

```
string s = "some text drop here some words table_name another text";
var regex = new Regex(@"drop (.*?) table_name");
var match = regex.Match(s);
string words;
if (match.Success)
    words = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Some explanations. Pattern `drop (.*?) table_name` matches everythig starting with `drop`, then any number (specified by `*` with ungreedy modifier `?`) of any symbols (specified by `.`) until `table_name`.

If match was successful, you can get that words between `drop` and `table_name` as `match.Groups[1].Value` since I've included that symbols in capturing group by specifying `(.*?)` in pattern.

Also you can get the whole text matching pattern from `match.Groups[0].Value`.

Have a look to [Regex Quick Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information about regualr expressions in C#.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, May I know your idea about below situation? I have list of tables which need to check in developer ddl script and if I identify them I should inform the user. in this case I have 32 tables which need to check in the ddl file, in your point of view, is it better I have one pattern and mention all the tables name or use a loop and call match for each word separately?

Comment: @rima I think it will be better to use a loop. If you will include all the names into one pattern it may slowdown matching significantly. Also pattern having all table names will be much less readable and harder to modify later.

Comment: I follow your approach, working fine. would u mind help me to arrest some script like "alter table table_A modify cc varchar2(1);"   or  
"alter table table_A modify cc varchar2(1) /"    ? I dont know how to tell to regex that a sql statement might stop with semicolon or slash I used this pattern "pattern = @"ALTER\s*TABLE\s*" + searchTxt + "(.*?)   XXX". would u mind help me what should I put instead of XXX

Comment: @rima well, you can simply use `[;/]`. It matches any one of the enclosed characters.

Comment: Thanks again, I also found it after I wrote my comment... Thanks

Comment: I am so sorry again I have one more question: I used like below
   pattern = @"ALTER\s*TABLE\s*" + searchTxt + "(.*?)[;/]";
                        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                        }

in this case if developer put semicolon or slash on next line it cannot recognize it. I tried to change RegexOptions to multiline but again it couldnt catch it, do u know why?

Comment: I added my sample to my question in above

Comment: @rima it should be `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline` in your case, not Multiline.

Comment: I changed it but still it is not working let me I put my code in above u correct me.

Comment: @rima again: it should be both IgnoreCase and SingleLine there (i.e. `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline`) , not `Multiline`. `RegexOptions.Singleline` changes the meaning of the dot (.) so it matches every character (instead of every character except \n) - this is exactly you're searching for since you have `(.*?)[;/]` in your pattern.

Comment: I added RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline but output became so funny, I dont know why it is repeating the statement

Comment: if I want to have at least one white space before and after my table name what should I use in my pattern?

Comment: Have you had a look to the regex syntax reference I've suggested? There is whole section named "Quantifiers" there, it contains exact answer: `+` "Matches the previous element one or more times". I cant teach you all regex features in comments - you should try to learn something by yourself too.

Comment: I did my best but I dont know why it is so complicated for me to understand it... :(